# Why is my ActionBlock not executed when my BroadcastBlock posts?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dataflow

I am trying to understand [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) in C#, so I wrote a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7hLNBC) and I'm curious why my action blocks are not executing in my example.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numberOfProducers = 1;
        var numberOfConsumers = 10;
        
        var allProducers = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfProducers).Select(x => new BroadcastBlock<double>(d =>
            {
                return d;
            },
            new DataflowBlockOptions()
            {
                BoundedCapacity = 500
            }));
        
        var allConsumers = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfConsumers).Select(x => new ActionBlock<double>(d =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Consuming {0} on Thread ID: {1}", d, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
            },
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
            {
                BoundedCapacity = 500
            }));
        
        foreach (var producer in allProducers)
        {
            foreach (var consumer in allConsumers)
            {
                producer.LinkTo(consumer);
            }
        }

        Parallel.For(0, 20, (i) =>
        {
            foreach (var producer in allProducers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Posting {0} on Thread ID: {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
                producer.Post(i);
            }
        }

        );
    }
}
```

An example of output from this program is as follows

> Posting 0 on Thread ID: 18
>
> Posting 10 on Thread ID: 16
>
> Posting 1 on Thread ID: 17
>
> Posting 11 on Thread ID: 19
>
> Posting 2 on Thread ID: 18
>
> Posting 4 on Thread ID: 17
>
> Posting 5 on Thread ID: 17
>
> Posting 6 on Thread ID: 17
>
> Posting 3 on Thread ID: 18
>
> Posting 12 on Thread ID: 18
>
> Posting 7 on Thread ID: 17
>
> Posting 16 on Thread ID: 19
>
> Posting 8 on Thread ID: 17
>
> Posting 17 on Thread ID: 19
>
> Posting 9 on Thread ID: 17
>
> Posting 18 on Thread ID: 19
>
> Posting 19 on Thread ID: 19
>
> Posting 13 on Thread ID: 18
>
> Posting 14 on Thread ID: 18
>
> Posting 15 on Thread ID: 18

I would expect there to be several lines mixed in showing the action blocks consuming the data being posted on the broadcast block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy evaluation is why the action blocks are not getting executed.

`allProducers` and `allConsumers` are lazy evaluated, so every time they are enumerated new producers and new consumers are being produced. Therefore, the producer referenced in `producer.LinkTo(consumer)` is a different producer than what is referenced in `producer.Post(i)`

I realized this when stepping through the code in a debugger, and when paused at `producer.Post(i)` it was showing that the producer currently in scope had 0 targets linked to it.

The solution is adding `ToList` or `ToArray` to definitions of `allProducers` and `allConsumers`

```
var allProducers = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfProducers).Select(x => new BroadcastBlock<double>(d =>
        {
            return d;
        })).ToList();

var allConsumers = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfConsumers).Select(x => new ActionBlock<double>(d =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Consuming {d} on Thread ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); ;
        })).ToList();
```